# Setting background-color for Flex Tree component..?

Tags: apache-flex, tree, background-color

I have a Flex Tree component in my app. I set the icons for open and close.
BUT I can't find something about changing the default background-color from white to something different.

obviously there is no background-color setable in css...

any ideas?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

myTree.setStyle( "backgroundColor", 0xFF66600 );

or

backgroundColor="blue"